# Bind WPF DataGrid to one-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a simple one-dimensional array:

```
class Cylinder {
    private float[] vector = new float[3] {4,5,6};
    public float[] Vector = { get; set; }
}
```

In my XAML, I have created a `DataGrid` with some simple binding:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Vector, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
<Grid>
```

I then set the `DataContext` of `MyGrid` to an instance of the `Cylinder` class. The window displays with the `DataGrid` control, but I have 2 problems:

1. The `DataGrid` is populated with the right data, but in a strange way. I get a 3x3 grid with the first row all '4's, the second row all '5's, and the third row all '6's.
2. When I try to edit any of the 9 cells, I get an exception:

> Two-way binding requires Path or XPath

I suppose I could just make three separate `TextBox` controls, but I thought this would be more elegant.

Comment: The 3 column bindings are identical, so why would you expect them to show different information? Ah ... Did you expect to see 4 5 6 on a single row? No, each item in the collection represents a row.

Comment: As for the second point "When I try to edit any of the (9!) cells, I get an exception "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath".", There is no explicit setter defined for the values in vector field.

Comment: I get what @Richardissimo is stating regarding identical column bindings, I realized that wasn't going to work, but couldn't come up with a better implementation.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to display 4 5 and 6 on as single row.  If each item in the collection represents a row, it would appear that maybe I need a collection of 3-item arrays?  And my collection just happens to have 1 item (and hence one row)?  Can I actually use a 3-item array, or do I need to create an object or struct with actual fields, and put the object/struct into a collection?

Comment: You can do what you like in WPF... You just need to have asked that in the question. You could use an ItemsControl, and define the PanelTemplate to be a horizontal StackPanel, and put a TextBox in the ItemTemplate. That would work with your existing data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a one-dimensional array, so how are you expecting it to bind to 3 columns? Think about it, the `DataGrid` is like a display for a two-dimensional array, the columns are the x axis, and the rows are the y axis. So your one-dimensional array must go in the rows of one column.

**EDIT** To represent a more complex type as you mentioned in your comments, you can use `DataTable` if you bind the `DataGrid` directly to the data (only for very simple projets) or better `List<>` if you bind to business objects. Here is an example:

Change your class to have the three properties that you want (give them more meaningful name than this example):

```
public class Cylinder {
    public float Vector1 = { get; set; };
    public float Vector2 = { get; set; };
    public float Vector3 = { get; set; };
}
```

Now you can bind your `DataGrid` directly to this class for testing, but in a real application where data is coming from some source like a database, you create a list of this class:

```
var cylinders = new List<Cylinder>();
```

And then populate it with the data coming from the database:

```
foreach(var row in myTable) {
    var c = new Cylinder();
    c.Vector1 = 4;
    c.Vector2 = 5;
    c.Vector3 = 6;
    cylinders.Add(c);
}
```

And now you can bind your `DataGrid` to `cylinders`. The grid will have three columns representing the three properties of the `Cylinder` class, and as many rows as you have in `myTable`.

Comment: A one-dimensional array is just a subset of a two-dimensional array, right?  It should be possible to display a data set of Y records of X fields where each row is a record and each column is a field.  I can then say that for my particular data set, there Y=1 and X=3 so there is only one row with 3 fields.

Comment: Yes and no. You can consider a one-dimensional array is just a subset of a two-dimensional array if you like, but then it will be Y=3 and X=1, not the other way around. The columns in the `DataGrid` are the dimensions of the array and the rows are the items in each dimension. If you want to do it the other way, you'll have to code it yourself because the `DataGrid` is not designed for that. If the number of items is fixed and will never change, then that's pretty easy, but that's very rarely the case.

Comment: I get what you are saying in terms of rows vs columns.  I think in my case I'm OK, because the 3 items are closely related (fields if you will) of a single record.  I could have multiple records but in this application it turns out I only have one.  So I think I am following the intent of `DataGrid` where each row is a record and the columns are the fields.  Based on that I think my mistake was capturing in an array.  It would appear that it might make more sense to capture in a structure which is then contained in a collection that is bound to the control.

Comment: Yes, now you got it right. If you bind your `DataGrid` to a `DataTable` with one record and three columns, you will get exactly what you want. And if you ever get more records, it will continue to work and the `DataGrid` will successfully show more rows. And yes, an array is like a table with one column and many records. To represent a more complex type, use `List<>`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Got it.  An array was already implicitly a collection.  I think this resolves my problem.  I've heard conflicting information on whether I have to bind the DataGrid to a List<> as you show or to an ObservableCollection<>.  The two don't seem to be related (inherited or siblings).  Is there a benefit of one or the other?

Comment: The only difference is how you want to reflect the changes when your data change. I prefer to bind to a `List<>` and handle the changes by myself (e.g. re-populate the list and re-bind it), but if you bind to an `ObservableCollection<>`, then your `DataGrid` will automatically reflect the changes that you make to the collection.